# Loop throws exception can't cast Null to String

Tags: c#, linq

I've stubled up on this in the code I've inherited, as it were and turns out it is Linq and I've not Linq-ed before. I've looked at some examples but I guess it is not 100% Linq issue, but perhaps it is.

I've got this construct:

`var categories = dtResults.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["Cat"]).Distinct().ToList();`

that returs 400 some category designators as string. The `dtResults` is a `DataTable` that get its data from a query.

Next I loop through the `categories` and the on first iteration I get a `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.` error because the `category` at index 0 is null in thes loop: `foreach(string category in categories)`.

I can't change the data but I could insers a white space, but how do I do it?

**UPDATE**
The loop as @flup requested:

```
foreach (string category in categories)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < WucEntries2.Length; i++)
        {
            drOutput = dtOutput.NewRow();
            drOutput["Category"] = category;
            drOutput["SubCategory "] = subCategories[i];

            drResults = dtResults.Select(String.Format("Category = '{0}' AND SubCategory = '{1}'", category, subCategories[i]));
            if (drResults.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dtResults.Columns)
                {
                    drOutput[column.ColumnName] = drResults[0][column.ColumnName];
                }
            }
            dtOutput.Rows.Add(drOutput);
        }
```

Comment: Can we see the loop, in particular the type of the variable you use to iterate? Is it a var or a string?

Comment: Added the loop as you requested. Here is another issue I've discovered as I'm testing this. The subcategory has a data that exceeds a column width and it throws MaxLimit violation.

Comment: Since category can be null, it's safer to write `foreach (var category in categories)`. Does this solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast `DBNull` to `string`, but you can cast `null` to `string`, so maybe:

```
var categories = dtResults.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r["Cat"] == DBNull.Value ? (string)null : r["Cat"].ToString())
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

This would also make your list a `List<string>` instead of `List<object>`.

Comment: This version worked, however the requirement has changed such that when the Category is null, I skip the record all together so I'm removing it before my foreach loop. Thanks for all your input. I guess I better start taking Linq seriously...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try :

```
var categories = dtResults.AsEnumerable().Select(r => Convert.ToString(r["Cat"]))
                                         .Distinct()
                                         .ToList();
```

Hope this will help

Comment: This kept throwing the same exception, Joe's version below worked. Thanks for you input.